# Rolling over increment of number in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a string that represents a kind of version. I would like to increment it and if the second part exceeds 9 
to go to the next higher number
The following seems to work. I was wondering if there is a more succinct way to do this

```
FIRST=$(echo -n "$VERSION"| cut -d "." -f 1)  
SECOND=$(echo -n "$VERSION"|cut -d "." -f 2)  
SECOND=$((SECOND + 1))  
if [[ $SECOND -ge 10 ]]; then  
    SECOND="0"  

fi  
FIRST=$(($FIRST + 1))

NEW_NUMBER=$FIRST.$SECOND
```

Examples:

```
Input: 102.8 Output: 102.9     
Input: 102.9 Output: 103.0
```

Comment: A change in the first part of the version number does not correspond to a new major release?

Comment: @Kusalananda: yes but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf '%s + 0.1\n' "$VERSION" | bc
```

This adds 0.1 to the floating point number in `$VERSION`.

Testing:

```
$ VERSION=10.2
$ printf '%s + 0.1\n' "$VERSION" | bc
10.3

$ VERSION=10.9
$ printf '%s + 0.1\n' "$VERSION" | bc
11.0
```